# syntax error near str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-max(ren_date)>=7

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW HWP_LASTRENEWED (REGNO, WPNO, PERMITSTATUS, PROCESSSTATUS, LASTRENDATE, DAYS, HTYPE, SRNO) AS 
  (
select regno, wpno, permitstatus, processstatus, max(ren_date) as lastrendate,
str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-max(ren_date) days , 'renw' as htype, '0' as srno
from hwp_renewal
having permitstatus='RENEWED'
and str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-max(ren_date)>=7
group by wpno, permitstatus, regno, processstatus
union
select reg_no as regno, wp_no as wpno, permitstatus, processstatus, permitdate as lastrendate,
(str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-permitdate) as days, 'req' as htype, srno
from hwp_hotwork where wp_no is null and reg_no is null and
( (permitstatus='REQUESTED' and processstatus='REQ') or (permitstatus='APPROVED' and processstatus='APPR') )
and str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-permitdate >=7
);
```

what is correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `HAVING` clause has to be after the `GROUP BY`. Simple as that.
2. You were missing parenthesis in your union select.

`CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW HWP_LASTRENEWED (
  REGNO,
  WPNO,
  PERMITSTATUS,
  PROCESSSTATUS,
  LASTRENDATE,
  DAYS,
  HTYPE,
  SRNO
) AS (
  select
    regno,
    wpno,
    permitstatus,
    processstatus,
    max(ren_date) as lastrendate,
    str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(), '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d-%b-%Y') - max(ren_date) as days,
    'renw' as htype,
    '0' as srno
  from
    hwp_renewal
  group by
    wpno,
    permitstatus,
    regno,
    processstatus
  having
    permitstatus = 'RENEWED'
    and days >= 7
)
union
  (
    select
      reg_no as regno,
      wp_no as wpno,
      permitstatus,
      processstatus,
      permitdate as lastrendate,
      str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(), '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d-%b-%Y') - permitdate as days,
      'req' as htype,
      srno
    from
      hwp_hotwork
    where
      wp_no is null
      and reg_no is null
      and (
        (
          permitstatus = 'REQUESTED'
          and processstatus = 'REQ'
        )
        or (
          permitstatus = 'APPROVED'
          and processstatus = 'APPR'
        )
      )
      and days >= 7
  )`

Comment: There is another issue with the use of the `HAVING` clause.  It might have been used as an intended overload of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are converting `SYSDATE()` to a string, and then back to a date again.  Instead, just use it directly with `DATEDIFF`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW HWP_LASTRENEWED AS (
    SELECT
        regno,
        wpno,
        permitstatus,
        processstatus,
        MAX(ren_date) AS lastrendate,
        DATEDIFF(MAX(ren_date), SYSDATE()) days,
        'renw' AS htype,
        '0' AS srno
    FROM hwp_renewal
    WHERE permitstatus = 'RENEWED'
    GROUP BY wpno, permitstatus, regno, processstatus
    HAVING DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), MAX(ren_date)) >= 7

    UNION

    SELECT
        reg_no AS regno,
        wp_no as wpno,
        permitstatus,
        processstatus,
        permitdate AS lastrendate,
        DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), permitdate) AS days
        'req' as htype,
        srno
    FROM hwp_hotwork
    WHERE wp_no IS NULL AND reg_no IS NULL AND
        ((permitstatus = 'REQUESTED' AND processstatus = 'REQ') OR
         (permitstatus = 'APPROVED' AND processstatus = 'APPR')) AND
        DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), permitdate) >= 7
);
```

Comment: Your SQL does not validate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in order 
1) **FROM & JOINs** determine & filter rows 
2) **WHERE** more filters on the rows 
3) **GROUP BY** combines those rows into groups 
4) **HAVING** filters groups 
5) **ORDER BY** arranges the remaining rows/groups 
6) **LIMIT** filters on the remaining rows/groups

HAVING Clause has use after the GROUP BY Clause
Modified Query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW HWP_LASTRENEWED (REGNO, WPNO, PERMITSTATUS, PROCESSSTATUS, LASTRENDATE, DAYS, HTYPE, SRNO) AS 
  (
select regno, wpno, permitstatus, processstatus, max(ren_date) as lastrendate,
str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-max(ren_date) days , 'renw' as htype, '0' as srno
from hwp_renewal
group by wpno, permitstatus, regno, processstatus
having permitstatus='RENEWED'
and str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-max(ren_date)>=7
union
select reg_no as regno, wp_no as wpno, permitstatus, processstatus, permitdate as lastrendate,
(str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-permitdate) as days, 'req' as htype, srno
from hwp_hotwork where wp_no is null and reg_no is null and
( (permitstatus='REQUESTED' and processstatus='REQ') or (permitstatus='APPROVED' and processstatus='APPR') )
and str_to_date(date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%b-%Y'),'%d-%b-%Y')-permitdate >=7
);
```